# conditional expectation with two signals

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am quite embarrassed to ask you this question but I am stuck.

I have to compute the following conditional expectation : $E[\theta|x_i,y]$.
I know how to compute the basic E[X|Y]E[X|Y] but I definitely do not know how to compute E[X|Y,Z]E[X|Y,Z]. Can someone please orient for the first step?

with

$\theta\sim N(0,\sigma_\theta^2)$

$y=\theta+\eta$, where $\eta\sim N(0,\sigma_\eta^2)$

$x_i=\theta+\epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma_\epsilon^2)$

I know the result is $$E[\theta|x_i,y]=\frac{\sigma_\eta^2}{\sigma_\epsilon^2+\sigma_\eta^2}(x_t-y)+y$$ but I cannot find it.

I know how to compute the basic $E[X|Y]$ but I definitely do not know how to compute $E[X|Y,Z]$. Can someone please orient for the first step?

Thank you